# Is there any hack to know the actual concrete class of the generic of an instance at runtime?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance, reflection, java-8

I'd like to find a hack to infer the actual generic instance of another  instance's var in runtime, **without**:

- Changing my needed method signature (adding the helper parameter `Class<T>`, the obvious way)
- Having to `instanceof` all possible subtypes in a hardcoded way

  ```
  MyInterface<? extends Number> myInterface = whateverReturnsWildcardDoubleInterface();
  Class<?> type = inferInstanceType(myInterface);
  assert type == Double.class;  

  /** This is the method that represents the code I am looking for  with the conrete signature**/
  public <T extends Number> Class<T> inferInstanceType(MyInterface<T> myInterface){
      return T.class; //Concrete T (can or cannot be the very Number)  
  }
  ```

Ideally, it should return Double when T is particular subtype Integer,Double.. and Number when T is Number

I checked reflection, several "TypeResolver"/"GenericResolver" libs (as the one in Spring or others in Github), but I cannot fin a way to hack it.

**EDIT:** I reached the conclusion that he only feasible way to do that would be some kind of very complex reflection through the stack trace up to the acutal line that passes the type in the very instantiation

**EDIT2:** I know it's stupid... but I solved it by simply adding a `T getT()` method to my interface, so I could `return myInterface.getT().getClass()`

Comment: Not possible due to erasure...

Comment: Yes, because it's _impossible_.  Learn about type erasure.

Comment: I don't want to disregard you, but I've seen these impossibles in a lot of questions and eventually somebody finds a smart tricky way to approach the problem,  that is why I ask about a hack. I know you can get the types using reflection if the instance class is typed through an interface (like in MyInterfaceDouble extends MyInterface<Double>, for instance

Comment: Yes. And in this case, you want to find out what `?` is through reflection and this is not possible. What is your use-case?

Comment: It looks like you might be testing or debugging as you are looking for a "hack." If you know the concrete type of `MyInterface`, and it has a field of type `T`, you can get the `Class<?>` for that field using reflection and get its type just as if it were not generic.

Comment: The use case is too complex and abstract, and I know it is not a good pattern, so I'll avoid it, just experimenting with the posisbilities of the compiler. Perhaps a non-reflection way?

Comment: ... in certain very narrow cases.

Comment: I EDITED the question at the end to wonder about the only possible approach that could work in my case

Comment: First, there is no guaranty that the creator of an object is on the stack at all, second, Reflection doesn’t provide you the ability to inspect the code at all, not to speak of such deep analysis, third, type erasure affects the executable byte code as well, don’t expect to find more information there than you already have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Disclaimer:** This solution is provided as a **hack** tailored to my understanding of your setup, i.e. one generic interface with a single type parameter, multiple classes, which are not themselves generic, directly implementing this one interface alone, and implementing no other generic interfaces, directly or indirectly.

Assuming that all of the above is true, there is a relatively straightforward way of hacking a solution: calling `getClass().getGenericInterfaces()` returns a `Type` object that provides the actual type with which your generic interface has been instantiated.

```
interface MyInterface<T extends Number> {
    T getVal();
}
class DoubleImpl implements MyInterface<Double> {
    public Double getVal() {return 42.42; }
}
...
public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
    MyInterface<? extends Number> x = new DoubleImpl();
    Type[] ifs = x.getClass().getGenericInterfaces();

    System.out.println(ifs.length);
    for (Type c : ifs) {
        System.out.println(c);
        Type[] tps = ((ParameterizedType)c).getActualTypeArguments();
        for (Object tp : tps) {
            System.out.println("===="+tp); // <<== This produces class java.lang.Double
        }
    }
}
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/jpvuHV)

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes, shame on you for saying "here's the hack" without a detailed "here's the special cases in which it works."  What's common to all these hacks is: there needs to be a 1:1 correspondence between the classfile and the specific type arguments.  So this works for generic specializations like DoubleImpl (rare), and also for inner class instances (slightly less rare).  But this fails for the other (100-epsilon)% of the cases.

Comment: What makes you think that his case matches the special case *you* have chosen? And…do you actually know what kind of special case you have chosen and why it works (in contrast to other scenarios)?

Comment: @Holger Why do you insist that I have chosen a special case? Haven't OP described *his* case well enough? I mean, he's got one interface with one generic parameter constrained as `<T extends Number>` and multiple classes implementing it; he wants to pull the actual `T` from an object instance implementing that interface, without having static access to the actual type `T`. My hack does exactly that. My biggest assumption is that OP' concrete classes do not implement other generic interfaces.

Comment: @Holger Perhaps it would be easier if you forked [this demo](http://ideone.com/jpvuHV) and modify it in a way that it returns a wrong result?

Comment: http://ideone.com/SB6Te9 just two different examples, both parametrized with `<Integer>`, neither of them processed correctly. Note that these are the common cases, e.g. like with `List<SomeType> l=new ArrayList<>();` You don’t create a subclass of `ArrayList` to aid such a hack… If you wanted to do that, you had to create a subclass for each possible parametrization.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The value of StackOverflow (in the words of Joel Spolsky), is *not* primarily about answering the OPs question, but about creating a persistent artifact that many others users will land on and learn from.  Saying "there's a simple workaround" and failing to characterize the limitations of that workaround is confusing thousands of future visitors.  And for no benefit at all!  You probably knew the limitations -- what's wrong with just saying them straight out?  The result is, your answer is fundamentally misleading. And for no good reason.

Comment: @BrianGoetz Personally, I strongly dislike "don't try" answers, for they discourage the reader from trying. I find this particular solution useful enough to post as an answer, because the dismissive "not possible due to type erasure" is simply not true.

Comment: @Holger Thanks for a useful example! This one fork of the code is worth a dozen of comments with explanations of what's wrong.

Comment: The difference between “not possible” and “possible in a single narrow case” is thin, but you can let the OP judge, if you put everything on the table. Btw., it’s even possible to [have a class that fits into the description but fails](http://ideone.com/8naAxH) because it’s not Generic but has a type parameter in its surrounding context.

Comment: Thanks for your effort. This is not resolving the problem in the fashion of my sample with a method to fullfill, but imposing me to declare every typeable interface as a concrete subinterface (then those libs I tested would work as well). I already knew that trick as I showed in some comment, but as I said, I'd like to respect the signature of my helper method, Sorry if I was not clear enough. Look the new EDIT, perhaps it helps to show a way.

Comment: I mean a way to iterate over the instance passings through the stack using reflection until we can find someway the original line that instantiates the instance and then we can infer the diamond generic used for so: <Double> <Integer> whatever. I know it's kinda ugly, but its the only thing it could work I think as long as reflection API allows it

Comment: @Whimusical It may not always be possible to catch the instantiation, because it may be off the stack by then. I think I understand your solution, but I am not sure that I fully understand the reason making you jump through all these hoops, e.g. avoiding the idiomatic solution of passing the class?

Comment: I think I found a very obvious solution.... :p, which stil complies with my 2 requirements... simply adding a `T getT()` method in my interface,, so I can do return `myInterface.getT().getClass()`... I know its stupid... I did not realize

Answer (score -3):

As assylias pointed out, Java's erasure will make that information unavailable at runtime - and thus a need for a hack.

On the assumption that `myInterface` has a getter for `T`, as in, `MyInterface.getValue():T` (or the hack would be to add it) you could do something like this (ignoring the possibility that `getValue()` could return `null`):

```
public <T extends Number> Class<T> inferInstanceType(MyInterface<T> myInterface){
    return myInterface.getValue().getClass()
}
```

Below is the full implementation

```
public class Q34271256 {

  public static interface MyInterface<T> {
    T getValue();
  }

  public static class MyDoubleClass implements MyInterface<Double> {
    private final Double value;
    public MyDoubleClass(Double value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public Double getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }

  public static class MyIntegerClass implements MyInterface<Integer> {
    private final Integer value;
    public MyIntegerClass(Integer value) {
      this.value = value;
    }
    @Override
    public Integer getValue() {
      return value;
    }
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  public static <T extends Number> Class<T> inferInstanceType(MyInterface<T> myInterface){
    Number value = myInterface.getValue();
    if (value == null) return null;
    return (Class<T>)value.getClass();
  }

  public static void main(String...args) {
    List<MyInterface<? extends Number>> list = Arrays.asList(
        new MyDoubleClass(1.1),
        new MyIntegerClass(5)
    );
    for (MyInterface<? extends Number> myInterface : list) {
      Class<?> type = inferInstanceType(myInterface);
      System.out.printf("%s inferred type is %s\n",
          myInterface.getClass().getName(),
          type.getName());
    }
  }
}
```

And the output should look something like this:

```
MyDoubleClass inferred type is java.lang.Double
MyIntegerClass inferred type is java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: The value being of type `Double` or `Integer` doesn’t prove that `T` is `Double` or `Integer`. It’s still possible that `T` is `Number`, `Serializable` or `Object`, to name some examples.